# Show that $S=\{(0,y):y\in \Bbb R-\{0\}\}$ is a subgroup of $G=(((\Bbb R \times (\Bbb R-\{0\})),⊥)$ for $(x,y)⊥(x',y')=(x+x'y,yy').$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Suppose that $G=(((\Bbb R \times (\Bbb R-\{0\})),⊥)$ is group. Show that $S=\{(0,y):y\in \Bbb R-\{0\}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
>
> Here $$(x,y)⊥(x',y')=(x+x'y,yy').$$

What should i do next? Are these subgroup conditions? $S\not\in \emptyset $ and $a⊥b^{-1}\in S,\forall_{a,b\in S}$? Do I have to check that $S$ is a group?

$(0,y_1)((0,y_2)⊥(0,y_3))=(0,y_1)⊥(0+0y_2,y_2y_3)=(0+0y_1,y_1y_2y_3)=(0,y_1y_2y_3)\\((0,y_1)⊥(0,y_2))⊥(0,y_3)=(0+0y_1,y_1y_2)⊥(0,y_3)=(0+0y_1,y_1y_2y_3)=(0,y_1y_2y_3)\Rightarrow$ Associativity

$(0,y_1)⊥(e_1,e_2)=(0,y_1)\\(0,y_1)⊥(e_1,e_2)=(0+e_1y_1,y_1e_2)=\begin{cases}0+e_1y_1=0\\y_1e_2=y_1\end{cases}\Rightarrow e_1=0\wedge e_2=1,e=(0,1)$
Identity element

$(0,y_1)⊥(0,y')=e\\(0,y_1)⊥(0,y')=(0+0y_1,y_1y')\Rightarrow y_1y'=1\Rightarrow y'=y_1^{-1},(0,y_1^{-1})\\(0,y_1)⊥(0,y_1^{-1})=(0+0y_1,y_1y_1^{-1})=(0,1)=e$

$a⊥b^{-1}$

What about this condition, does it all make sense?

Comment: Why are you dealing with commutativity ?

Comment: Sorry its Associativity

Comment: Use `$\bot$` for $\bot$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to show that $S\neq\varnothing$ and $a\,\bot\, b^{-1}\in S$ for all $a, b\in S.$ This is called the one-step subgroup test/lemma.

Here is the answer . . .

> If $(0, a), (0, b)\in S$, then $$(0,a)\,\bot\, \left(0,\frac{1}{b}\right)=\left(0+\frac{0}{b}, \frac{a}{b}\right)\in S.$$ Since you have found $e\in S$, we have $S\neq \varnothing$. This is enough to prove $S\le G$.

Comment: I have a question for you regarding this condition $a\,\bot\, b^{-1}\in S$ that's correct when $(0,a)\bot(0,b)$ and what $(..,a)\bot(..,b) $  
if there is no zero here, how should I check this condition since I have a and b and there are 4 places?$(a_1,a_2)\bot(b_1,b_2)?$  
I know this is not in the task but it bothered me

Comment: By that which we call a rose by any other name would smell as sweet, @vmahth1. (Any name will do.) Yes, use four symbols (or even four collections of symbols) when there are four entities involved.